# If $\tau=\inf\{t>0\mid B_t\notin B(0,R)\}$ does $|B_{\tau}|\leq R$ or $|B_\tau|\leq R$ a.s.?

Tags: probability

Let $(B_t)$ a Brownian motion starting at $0$ and let $B(0,R)$ the open ball of radius $R$. Let $\tau=\inf\{t>0\mid B_t\notin B(0,R)\}$. Does $|B_\tau(\omega )|\leq R$ for all $\omega $ or we only have $|B_\tau|\leq R$ a.s. ?

Comment: Is $B_t$ continuous, or merely continuous a.s.?  Do we have $B_0 = 0$ or merely $B_0 = 0$ a.s.?  I think: if your question depends on what happens with probability zero, then anything goes.

Comment: @GEdgar: A Brownian motion is normally continuous a.s. and start at $0$ a.s., no ?

Comment: I agree.  But then we certainly can only conclude $|B_\tau|\le R$ a.s.  and not $|B_\tau|\le R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|B_{\tau}| \leq R$ holds at every point $\omega$ where $\tau (\omega) <\infty$. But we can only assert that $\tau (\omega) <\infty$  almost surely.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now :)